# Matching a question mark in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set up some 301 redirects for old Kayako helpdesk URL's. The old URL's were;

`example.com/index.php?/rest_of_url`

I've set up rewriting so the URL's are prettier `example.com/rest_of_url`, and I'm trying to 301 redirect all old URL's to new. I've tried the following but they don't appear to work;

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?/(.*)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.php\?/(.*)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.(.*)/(.*)?$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

I can't quite figure it out.

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|api|console|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|index\.php|tiny_mce_gzip\.php|cron|onsite|staff|rss|setup|visitor|winapp|wallboard|__swift) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|htm|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|index\.php|tiny_mce_gzip\.php|__swift) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|htm|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the question mark is not in the RewriteRule url.
You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

`%1`is the first `(.*)` in the last `RewriteCond`.

In your case, without loop, use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't appear to be working correctly though, it seems to be redirecting to `example.com/rest_of_url?/rest_of_url` any ideas?

Comment: Yes, sorry, now it's ok, with `?` after `%1`

Comment: Thank you, that does work. Only problem is that it does an infinite redirect loop. I'm not sure why this is. I've updated the post with the entire `.htaccess` incase it's something else that's conflicting. Appreciate the help.

Comment: YES! You redirect a nonexistent file to `index.php?/$1` and after (before in this htaccess) you redirect link with `^/(.*)$`to the file in the query string... the loop.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding but but there is only one redirect in this .htaccess right? The other 2 are just rewrites that feed that URL string to index.php?

Comment: Yes, but you rewrite to the redirect, and rewrite to the redirect, rewri... When url change (rewrite), this htaccess is used again.

Comment: I edit the code with new RewriteCond, without loop problem in your case.

Comment: Thank you kind sir that worked perfectly, appreciate the help :)